# Android Studio activity not linking

Tags: java, android-studio, android-activity

I am in the process of making a login screen for my app in Android Studio. 
 
I have this in my `MainActivity.java`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewAccountActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

This in my `NewAccountActivity.java`:

```
public class NewAccountActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_account);
  }
}
```

And my `activity_new_account.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

But... It gives me an error from `NewAccountActivity.java`: `Cannot resolve symbol 'activity_new_account'` 
 
 
Does anyone know how to fix this, i've been googling for half an hour and I still got no answer.

Comment: Are you facing this error in after running the application or while compiling the code ?

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding the project (under the Build menu), and if that doesn't work, Invalidate Caches/Restart (under File). There's a glitch in recent Android versions with newly created layouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the current latest update, you get this kind of error pretty frequently. 
In order to fix try following below steps(which worked for me):

Click on the File from the menu

[image: Image reference for step 1]

Click on Invalidate caches/restart

[image: Image reference for step 2]

Now, wait for the android studio to restart and rebuild.

After that your problem should be solved